# Can we set default audience for facebook Share Dialog ios sdk?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

In my app sharing a link using Facebook Share Dialogue. Can we set default audience to '**Only Me**' option?
Here is the code:

```
params.link = linkURL;
params.name = name;
params.linkDescription = @"Desc";
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:params
                            clientState:nil
                                handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {}];
```

Here how to set value for default audience key?